# How to check the data format in PHP

Tags: php, date, formatting

I am trying to check a date format to see if I can check the data variable has certain format like MM-DD-YYYY. if not, then exit(). I am not sure how to check the format and would appreciate if any one can help me about it. Thanks...

```
$date=05/25/2010;    
if(XXXXX){
    // do something....
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I can't vote you guys yet.
Vote me and make me to 15 reputation and i give u all +1..:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression, as others have suggested. The ones posted before will accept invalid dates such as 99/99/9999 however. Here's an improved regex (lifed from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html))

```
$date_regex = '!^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$!';
if (preg_match($date_regex, $date)) {
   // do something
}
```

It will only take valid dates and it will also accept different separators (such as 05.20.2002 and 05-02-2002).

If you ask me it's bad user experience to force them to enter a particular format. YOU can handle different formats using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)().

Comment: Thanks man. I can't vote you guys yet. Vote me and make me to 15 reputation and i give u all +1

Comment: If I only want two formats like mm-dd-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd only, should i create two regular expressions??? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
if(preg_match("/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/"))
{
    do something
}
```

Comment: Note: takes invalid input (such as 00/00/0000)

Comment: Thanks man. I can't vote you guys yet. Vote me and make me to 15 reputation and i give u all +1

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do this to limit user's input, you can always use [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/strtotime) on the users input and convert it to a unix timestamp then use the [date()](http://www.php.net/date) function to display it how you want to.

If you really want to determine if it is in a certain format, or only require a certain format, a [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/preg_match) with a regular expression will be of assistance, I believe on that page they have examples of parsing dates. If not it would be something like this:

```
if (preg_match('~[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}~', $dateStr)) { echo 'Correct format'; }
```

The obvious flaw with that is the date may pass the format test, but may not be a valid date. In my opinion, accept any date in the user input and use the strtotime / date to get it to the format you want.

Comment: Thanks man. I can't vote you guys yet. Vote me and make me to 15 reputation and i give u all +1

Answer (score 1):

http://us.php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check a string to make sure it follows the MM-DD-YYYY pattern?

If so, I would suggest two checks: one to make sure it follows the general pattern of digits, and another to check that the months are first and days are second.

```
function checkDate( $date )
{

    if (preg_match("/[0|1][0-9]/[0-9][1-9]/[0-9]{4}/",$date)
    {
        if (substr($date,0,2)<=12 && substr($date,3,2)<=31)
        {
             return true;
        }
    }
    return false

}
```

**Update:** Added an additional check on the days to make sure it is valid, based on NullUser's comment

Comment: This still takes invalid input such as 12/99/2000

Comment: Thanks man. I can't vote you guys yet. Vote me and make me to 15 reputation and i give u all +1

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php