# PHP Date format question

Tags: php, date, format

Some folks helped me on 
[How to check the data format in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326316/how-to-check-the-data-format-in-php)
 post but I need to check two date formats MM-DD-YYYY and DD-MM-YY instead of one. Do I need to setup two regular expression???? Thanks for the help!!!

```
$date1=05/25/2010;    
$date2=25/05/10;    //I wish both of them would pass 

$date_regex = '!^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$!';

if (preg_match($date_regex, $date1)) {
  do something    
}

if (preg_match($date_regex, $date2)) {  // need second Reg. expression??
  do something    
}
```

Comment: Erm, you should put your dates into quotes. Otherwise `05/25/2010` is just an arithmetic expression (05 divided by 25 divided by 2010).

Comment: I know. In my application, I use mktime. my code is only for demo. purpose...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex

```
$date_regex = '!^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$!';
```

matches MM-DD-YYYY format.

The other you want to match is simple

```
$date_regex2 = '!^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.]\d\d$!';
```

You could just check if either is true.

```
if(preg_match($date_regex,$date) or preg_match($date_regex2,$date)){
  //match
}
```

Or you could combine them using

```
$mmddyyyy = '!^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$!';
$mmddyy = '!^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.]\d\d$!';
$regex = "($mmddyyyy|$mmddyy)";

if(preg_match($regex,$date){
  //match
}
```

Not the most elegant regex but it shold work just fine.