# how to print current date in php in special format

Tags: php, html, css

I have searched this question, but not got the exact result of this question. This format of date has not been answered here before.

I want to display the current date in this format. I attach the image of format.

[image: Date Format]

Can anyone please help me how to get current date like this format. and it will automatically changed according to time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the data format in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326316/how-to-check-the-data-format-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty basic [date formatting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
echo date('F j, Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i want to display the current date in this format.

This was the answer of my question.

```
 echo date('F j, Y');
```

Comment: Could you explain? Its the same format as the one above?